# Como faço para que o Jquery Mask não aceite números?

Tags: jquery, formulário

Estou recebendo um dado que seria os três primeiros dígitos carácteres alfabéticos e os outros 4 numéricos (Uma placa de veículo).

Vi em um site que para recebermos apenas letras no Jquey Mask, basta utilizar o "A"

Exemplo:

```
$('.placa').mask('AAA-0000');
```

Mas utilizando este exemplo, o usuário pode inserir números antes do hífen sem problemas algum...

Alguém sabe como posso resolver isto?

Answer (score 1):

Vou tentar deixar essa resposta bem completa já que essa pergunta é bem interessante e eu mesmo a tempos atrás estava a procura disso e creio que outras pessoas também irão procurar sobre isso.

Neste exemplo foi utilizado apenas

- HTML
- jQuery

Bem simples usando o plugin [jQuery Masked Input](https://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/), no exemplo há 3 campos, um apenas texto, outro texto e número e por fim apenas número.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#apenasnumero').mask('(99) 9999-9999');

  $('#apenasletra').mask('aaaaaaaa');

  $('#letrasnumeros').mask('********');
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- link para o plugin de mascara -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tutsmais.com.br/blog/arquivos/mascara/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
Apenas Letras:
<input type="text" id="apenasletra" />
<br>Letras e Números
<input type="text" id="letrasnumeros" />
<br>Apenas Número:
<input type="text" id="apenasnumero" />
<br>
```

Se tiver alguma dúvida, é só comentar.